# Cinnamon show an application in all workspaces

Tags: cinnamon

I have a number of monitors. I typically move between up to 4 or 5 workspaces for different areas of focus during the day (simply different projects, PyCharm for Python projects vs Eclipse for Java projects, e-mail and project management activities, etc.)

I would like to throw a chat application up on a monitor that would be mapped into all workspaces so that it's always up attracting my attention and doesn't change when I change workspaces.

I don't see in Cinnamon any option to do this and find no search expression getting me help in Google to solve it.

Comment: This really doesn't belong on SO, but if you right click the window you can choose `Always on visible workspace` which is what you want. Now i'm voting to close this question.

Comment: Thanks.  A reason it might belong is because the answer doesn't (didn't) turn up and now it will.

Comment: what answer? the reason it doesn't belong is because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: At SO not everything is only related to Programming, lots of people here try to get advice and help for Linux and Mac too.

Comment: [Here] is an issue which investigates how you can do that programatically, so there will be hard mapping between the window and that setting

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă: I think you forgot to actually link to something. :)

Comment: @SashaChedygov see my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, this is not possible in Cinnamon. It is a long standing [feature request](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/1052) (since 2012!).

However, there are alternatives to it. Namely, the program [`devilspie2`](http://www.nongnu.org/devilspie2/) (available in the repositories) allows one to manage windows and their placement, with the help of a small Lua script.

Here<sup>1</sup> is how I stick my Firefox and Pidgin window on all workspaces, while some other windows in a given workspace `WORK` (because I don't want to see them when I'm not working (: ).

```lua
-- Make windows of all these apps visible on all workspaces
GLOBAL_WINDOWS='Firefox;System Monitor;Pidgin'
if (GLOBAL_WINDOWS:find(get_application_name())) then
   pin_window();
end

-- Firefox should be tall maximised
if (get_application_name() == 'Firefox') then
   maximize_vertically();
end

-- Put the Sublime on their correct workspaces
if (get_application_name() == 'Sublime Text' and get_window_name():find('WORK')) then
  set_window_workspace(4);
end
```

This should be placed in a config file in your home directory. Check the documentation :). And don't forget to set `devilspie2` as the first startup app.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>also posted in that issue</sub>